# C++ - Xcode Program

Tags: c++, xcode, encryption

I am writing a program that extracts data from a text file and encrypts it. I am having some trouble with this. First of all there is an error at the getline(data,s[i]) part. Also the text file has two sentences but it only encrypts the second sentence. The other issue with that is It encrypts one letter at a time and outputs the sentence every time. It should output just the sentence encrypted.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
//Declare Variables
string s;

ifstream data;

//Uses Fstream to open text file
data.open ("/Users/MacBookPro/Desktop/data.txt");

// Use while loop to extract the data from the text file
    while(!data.eof()){
    getline(data,s);
        cout<< s << endl;
    }
//Puts the data from the text file into a string array

for(int i = 0; data.good(); i++){
    getline(data, s[i]);
    cout<< s <<endl;
}

// encrypts the string
if(data.is_open()){
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length();i++){

        s[i] += 2;


        cout << s << endl;

    }
}
```

return 0;
}

Comment: When you used the debugger, which line is causing the issue?  If you have not used the debugger, please do so before posting again.

Answer (score 1):

In the code below you already reach the end of the stream, and store the last line on the string s.

while(!data.eof()){

```
getline(data,s);
cout<< s << endl;
```

}

My suggestion is that you use a list of strings.

vector< string > s;

string tmp;

while(!data.eof()){

```
getline(data,tmp);
s.push_back(tmp);
cout<< s << endl;
```

}

The next step you loop through the list and do the encryption

for(i=0; i < s.size(); i++)

{

```
// encrypt s[i]
```

}

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

First I had to add this line to get "getline" to be recognised:

```
#include <string>
```

Then, there was indeed an error with the line:

```
getline(data, s[i]);
```

This is a compilation error, that function is expecting a stream and a string, but you pass it a stream and a char.
Changing that line for:

```
getline(data, s);
```

makes your program compile.

However it probably does not do what you want at this point, since the variable i from the for is being ignored.

I suggest that you check out some documentation on the getline function, then rethink what you want to do and try again.

You can fine some doc here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2whx1zkx(v=vs.100).aspx

Your other concern was that it output your string many times. This is normal, since your cout statement is inside in your encryption loop.

Move it outside the loop instead, to output it only one time once the encryption loop is done.

It is important to spend the time to understand what each line of your program is doing, and why you need it to achieve your goal.

Also when doing something that we find complicated, its easier to do one small part of it at a time, make sure it works, then continue with the next part.

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary string for containing each line and an integer since we're going to find the total number of lines to create an array for all of them.

```
string temp = "";
int numberOfLines = 0;
```

Now we try to find the total number of lines

```
while(data.good()) {
    getline(data, temp);
    cout << temp << endl;
    numberOfLines++;
}
```

Now we can create an array for all of the lines. This is a dynamic array which you can read on it for more information.

```
string * lines = new string[numberOfLines];
```

Now is the time to roll back and read encrypt all the lines. But first we have to go back to first position of file. That's why we use `seekg`

```
data.seekg(data.beg);
```

For each line we read, we'll put in the array and loop through each character, encrypt it and then show the whole sentence.

```
int i = 0;
while (data.good()) {
    getline(data, lines[i]);
    i++;
    for (int j = 0; lines[i].size(); j++ ) {
        lines[i].at(j) += 2;
    }
    cout << lines[i] << endl;
}
```

Voila!

Answer (score 0):

`s[i]` is a character in the string (actually, a character reference), not the string object itself. `string::operator[]` returns a `char&` in the docs. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).

Consider declaring a `std::vector<string> string_array;` and then use the `string_array.push_back(data)` member function to append strings from the file onto the vector. Use a for loop to iterate through the vector at a later time with a `vector<string>::iterator` or the `std::vector::size` function to get the length of the vector for a traditional for loop (via a call to `string_array.size()`). Use the square brackets to get each string from the vector (`string_array[0 or 1 or etc.]`).

Get characters from each string in the vector by using something like `string_array[n][m]` for the *mth* character of the *nth* string. Iterating over each character should be as simple as using the `string::length` member function to get the string length, and then another for loop.

Also, `std::cout << s << std::endl` is being used in the wrong places. To output each character, try `std::cout << s[i] << std::endl` instead, or `printf("%c", s[i])`, whichever you like.

I'd suggest not using an array to hold strings from the file because you don't know what the array's length will be at runtime (the file size could be unbounded), so a vector is better suited for this case.

Finally, if you need code, there's a beginner's forum post [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/55949/) that I think will help you out. It has a lot of code like yours, but you'll have to modify it for your purposes.

Finally, please use:

```
std::someCPPLibraryFunction(args);
```

instead of...

```
using namespace std;
someCPPLibraryFunction(args);
```